# No repetir Datos Unpivot

Tags: sql-server

Hola buen dia tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT CORTE_SISTEMA, VALOR_SISTEMA, VALOR_VEN
FROM   
   (select dat.EFECTIVO, dat.TARJETA, dat.EFECTIVO_VEN, dat.TARJETA_VEN
 from (SELECT '10' AS EFECTIVO, '20' AS TARJETA, '30' AS EFECTIVO_VEN, '40' AS TARJETA_VEN) dat) p   
UNPIVOT  
   (VALOR_SISTEMA  FOR CORTE_SISTEMA IN   
      (EFECTIVO, TARJETA)
)AS unpvt
UNPIVOT  
   (VALOR_VEN  FOR CORTE_VEN IN   
      (EFECTIVO_VEN, TARJETA_VEN)
)AS unpvt2
```

y me traer el siguiente resultado:

```
CORTE_SISTEMA   VALOR_SISTEMA   VALOR_VEN
EFECTIVO                10        30
EFECTIVO               10         40
TARJETA                20         30
TARJETA                 20        40
```

se fijan me repite CORTE DE SISTEMA (EFECTIVO, EFECTIVO, TARJETA Y TARJETA), quiero que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
 CORTE_SISTEMA  VALOR_SISTEMA   VALOR_VEN
    EFECTIVO                10        30
    TARJETA                 20        40
```

como le podria hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Hay una forma más versatil de hacer `unpivot` que llega a ser más eficiente. Es mediante el uso de `CROSS APPLY` y el constructor de tablas `VALUES`. Reacomodé la consulta para que sea más legible la solución.

```
WITH cteDatos AS(
    SELECT dat.EFECTIVO, 
        dat.TARJETA, 
        dat.EFECTIVO_VEN, 
        dat.TARJETA_VEN
    FROM (SELECT '10' AS EFECTIVO, '20' AS TARJETA, '30' AS EFECTIVO_VEN, '40' AS TARJETA_VEN) dat
)
SELECT unpvt.*
FROM  cteDatos  
 CROSS APPLY(VALUES('EFECTIVO', EFECTIVO, EFECTIVO_VEN),
                   ( 'TARJETA', TARJETA, TARJETA_VEN))unpvt(CORTE_SISTEMA, VALOR_SISTEMA, VALOR_VEN)
```

[Aquí](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/) hay un artículo en inglés que lo explica.